# How to optimize this php code?

Tags: php, optimization

I wrote a function which translates a word into an array with digits.
F.e.

```
$alphas = range('a', 'z');
function dig_to_string($string) {
     global $alphas;
     $array = str_split($string);
     foreach($array as $a) {
         $digits[] = array_search($a,$alphas);
     }
     return $digits;
}
$word = 'color';
$array = dig_to_string($word);
// Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 14 [2] => 11 [3] => 14 [4] => 17 )
// Because 'c' is the second alphabet's letter, 'o' is 14th and so on.
// Means 'a' has 0-index
```

Is there way to optimize it?

Comment: I'd start by fixing the name: `str_to_dig`

Comment: Agree. But how to optimize the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [ord()](http://www.php.net/ord)

```
function string_to_digits($string) {
    $start=ord('a');
    $length=strlen($string);
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
    {
        $digits[]=ord($string[$i])-$start;  
              // $digits[]=ord($string[$i]);   //If you want ASCII code to be returned

    }
    return $digits;
}
```

Comment: I'd probably say `$a = ord('a');` before the loop and use that instead of `97`, just so it's clearer what the loop's supposed to be doing.  (Might also want to find `strlen($string)` prior to the loop, for performance reasons...but eh.)

Comment: Which way is better for performace yours or this:
`$start = ord('a');
function string_to_digits($string) {
    global $start;
....`

Comment: Why you seem so inclined towards `global` ? All of the answers posted here are fine. Its up to you which one is more your coding style. My Answer is not necessarily any better than others

Answer (score 3):

Why not using map and get the code of each character using the difference with 'a'

```
function code($n){return ord($n)-ord('a')+1;}
$b = array_map("code", str_split("hello"));
```

Comment: +1 Nice thinking. Though `ord('a') + 1` can really be a constant... :)

Comment: You should consider uppercase letters as well as non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: Sure it would be ideal but my code is semantically equivalent to the expectation and answers the question, isn't it?

Comment: I mean only lowercase chars. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a bit better. I did not test it, but I think it should work ;-)

```
function dig_to_string($string)
{
    $len = strlen($string);
    $digits = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
        $digits[$i] = ord($string[$i])-97; //97 = ASCII for 'a'
    }
    return $digits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function str_to_dig($string) {
    static $map = null;
    if ($map === null) {
        $map = array_flip(range('a', 'z'));
    }

    return array_map(function ($char) use ($map) { return $map[$char]; }, str_split($string));
}
```

- initialize the char array only once **without using `global`**
- make a map you can directly access instead of searching through an array several times
- `array_map`, because *weeeee!* ^_^